# I am learning .map.. but I am having trouble with this problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, array.prototype.map

The Problem...

> Rewrite the example below using .map instead of a for-loop.
>
> ```
> let selectedMonths = [
>     { name: 'January', revenue: 10, expenses: 5, quarter: 1 },
>     { name: 'February', revenue: 7, expenses: 8, quarter: 1 },
>     { name: 'March', revenue: 15, expenses: 3, quarter: 1 }
> ]
>
> let monthlyProfitLabels = []
> for(let i = 0; i < selectedMonths.length; i++){
>     let month = selectedMonths[I]
>     let label = `${month.name}: ${month.revenue - month.expenses}`
>     monthlyProfitLabels.push(label)
> }
>
> console.log(monthlyProfitLabels)
> ```

**What they gave me to type in***

```
let selectedMonths = [
    { name: 'January', revenue: 10, expenses: 5, quarter: 1 },
    { name: 'February', revenue: 7, expenses: 8, quarter: 1 },
    { name: 'March', revenue: 15, expenses: 3, quarter: 1 } 
]

let monthlyProfitLabels = null; // <-- replace null

console.log(monthlyProfitLabels);
```

**What I typed so far...**

```
let monthlyProfitLabels = selectedMonths.map(function(month){
  let label = `${month.name}: ${month.revenue - month.expenses}`
    monthlyProfitLabels.push(label) 
})

console.log(monthlyProfitLabels);
```

It is telling me "*Can't access uninitialized variable*".. I'm so confused...
the backticks are there before `$` and after `}` for label but they aren't showing on here.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add an appropriate language-specific tag (like `PHP`, `JavaScript`, etc).

Comment: I think it might help is use the code formatting options to improve the readability of this question. You can check out this answer for how it works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `monthlyProfitLabels.push(label)` is the culprit. Study again what `map` does with the callback.

Answer (score 0):

`map` [(spec | MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - creates a new array from the values returned by the callback

```js
let selectedMonths = [
    { name: 'January', revenue: 10, expenses: 5, quarter: 1 },
    { name: 'February', revenue: 7, expenses: 8, quarter: 1 },
    { name: 'March', revenue: 15, expenses: 3, quarter: 1 } 
]
let monthlyProfitLabels = selectedMonths.map(function(month){
  let label = `${month.name}: ${month.revenue - month.expenses}`
  return label
})
```

You need return elements for `monthlyProfitLabels`

Answer (score 0):

Observation **:** [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. Hence, no need to do this unwanted code execution `monthlyProfitLabels.push(label)`. You have to simply return the `label`.

Demo **:**

```js
let selectedMonths = [
    { name: 'January', revenue: 10, expenses: 5, quarter: 1 },
    { name: 'February', revenue: 7, expenses: 8, quarter: 1 },
    { name: 'March', revenue: 15, expenses: 3, quarter: 1 }
];

let monthlyProfitLabels = selectedMonths.map(function(month){
  let label = `${month.name}: ${month.revenue - month.expenses}`
    return label; 
});

console.log(monthlyProfitLabels);
```